# How to lookup an EJB with appclient -client? (NamingException)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, jndi

Tried more than a few [ways](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28706634/262852) of looking up this `EJB` through `appclient` without success.

stacktrace for `JNDI` lookup failure:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/ejbClient$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/ejbClient$ gradle clean shadowJar
> Task :shadowJar
The SimpleWorkResult type has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use WorkResults.didWork() instead.


BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
4 actionable tasks: 4 executed
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/ejbClient$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/ejbClient$ appclient -client build/libs/ejbClient.jar Nov 06, 2017 5:13:34 PM net.bounceme.dur.ejb.client.App main
SEVERE: null
javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:global/EJBModule1/FooBean' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: ejb ref resolution error for remote business interfacenet.bounceme.dur.ejb.NewSessionBeanRemote [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.bounceme.dur.ejb.NewSessionBeanRemote]]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at net.bounceme.dur.ejb.client.App.run(App.java:19)
    at net.bounceme.dur.ejb.client.App.main(App.java:24)
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: ejb ref resolution error for remote business interfacenet.bounceme.dur.ejb.NewSessionBeanRemote [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.bounceme.dur.ejb.NewSessionBeanRemote]
    at com.sun.ejb.EJBUtils.lookupRemote30BusinessObject(EJBUtils.java:433)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.RemoteBusinessObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(RemoteBusinessObjectFactory.java:75)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getObjectInstance(SerialContext.java:527)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:487)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.bounceme.dur.ejb.NewSessionBeanRemote
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.ACCClassLoader.findClass(ACCClassLoader.java:237)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.sun.ejb.EJBUtils.getBusinessIntfClassLoader(EJBUtils.java:685)
    at com.sun.ejb.EJBUtils.loadGeneratedRemoteBusinessClasses(EJBUtils.java:462)
    at com.sun.ejb.EJBUtils.lookupRemote30BusinessObject(EJBUtils.java:413)
    ... 8 more

thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/ejbClient$
```

clean, build and deploy from Netbeans default `ant`:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/EJBModule1$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/EJBModule1$ asadmin list-applications
Nothing to list.
No applications are deployed to this target server.
Command list-applications executed successfully.
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/EJBModule1$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/EJBModule1$ ant -p
Buildfile: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/EJBModule1/build.xml
Builds, tests, and runs the project EJBModule1.
Main targets:

 -profile-pre72         Profile a J2EE project in the IDE.
 clean                  Clean build products.
 compile                Compile project.
 debug                  Debug project in IDE.
 default                Build whole project.
 dist                   Build distribution (JAR).
 dist-directory-deploy  Build distribution (JAR) - if directory deployment is not supported.
 dist-ear               Build distribution (JAR) to be packaged into an EAR.
 javadoc                Build Javadoc.
 profile                Profile a J2EE project in the IDE.
 run                    Deploy to server.
 test                   Run unit tests.
 test-single            Run single unit test.
 test-single-method     Run single unit test.
Default target: default
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/EJBModule1$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/EJBModule1$ ant clean run
Buildfile: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/EJBModule1/build.xml

-pre-init:

-init-private:

-init-userdir:

-init-user:

-init-project:

-init-macrodef-property:

-do-init:

-post-init:

-init-check:

-init-ap-cmdline-properties:

-init-macrodef-javac-with-processors:

-init-macrodef-javac-without-processors:

-init-macrodef-javac:

-init-macrodef-test-impl:

-init-macrodef-junit-init:

-init-macrodef-junit-single:

-init-test-properties:

-init-macrodef-junit-batch:

-init-macrodef-junit:

-init-macrodef-junit-impl:

-init-macrodef-testng:

-init-macrodef-testng-impl:

-init-macrodef-test:

-init-macrodef-junit-debug:

-init-macrodef-junit-debug-batch:

-init-macrodef-junit-debug-impl:

-init-macrodef-test-debug-junit:

-init-macrodef-testng-debug:

-init-macrodef-testng-debug-impl:

-init-macrodef-test-debug-testng:

-init-macrodef-test-debug:

-init-macrodef-java:

-init-debug-args:

-init-macrodef-nbjpda:

-init-macrodef-debug:

-init-taskdefs:

-init-ap-cmdline-supported:

-init-ap-cmdline:

init:

undeploy-clean:

deps-clean:

-do-clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/EJBModule1/build
   [delete] Deleting directory /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/EJBModule1/dist

-post-clean:

clean:

-pre-init:

-init-private:

-init-userdir:

-init-user:

-init-project:

-init-macrodef-property:

-do-init:

-post-init:

-init-check:

-init-ap-cmdline-properties:

-init-macrodef-javac-with-processors:

-init-macrodef-javac-without-processors:

-init-macrodef-javac:

-init-macrodef-test-impl:

-init-macrodef-junit-init:

-init-macrodef-junit-single:

-init-test-properties:

-init-macrodef-junit-batch:

-init-macrodef-junit:

-init-macrodef-junit-impl:

-init-macrodef-testng:

-init-macrodef-testng-impl:

-init-macrodef-test:

-init-macrodef-junit-debug:

-init-macrodef-junit-debug-batch:

-init-macrodef-junit-debug-impl:

-init-macrodef-test-debug-junit:

-init-macrodef-testng-debug:

-init-macrodef-testng-debug-impl:

-init-macrodef-test-debug-testng:

-init-macrodef-test-debug:

-init-macrodef-java:

-init-debug-args:

-init-macrodef-nbjpda:

-init-macrodef-debug:

-init-taskdefs:

-init-ap-cmdline-supported:

-init-ap-cmdline:

init:

-init-cos:

-init-deploy:

-deps-module-jar:

-deps-ear-jar:

deps-jar:

-pre-pre-compile:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/EJBModule1/build/classes

-pre-compile:

-copy-meta-inf:
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/EJBModule1/build/classes/META-INF

-do-compile:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/EJBModule1/build/empty
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/EJBModule1/build/generated-sources/ap-source-output
    [javac] Compiling 2 source files to /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/EJBModule1/build/classes

-post-compile:

compile:

-library-inclusion-in-archive-weblogic:

-library-inclusion-in-archive-by-user:

library-inclusion-in-archive:

-pre-dist:

-do-tmp-dist-without-manifest:

-do-tmp-dist-with-manifest:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/EJBModule1/dist
      [jar] Building jar: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/EJBModule1/dist/EJBModule1.jar

-do-dist-directory-deploy:

-post-dist:

dist-directory-deploy:

pre-run-deploy:

-pre-nbmodule-run-deploy:

-run-deploy-nb:

-init-deploy-ant:

-init-cl-deployment-env:

-parse-glassfish-web:

-parse-sun-web:

-no-parse-sun-web:

-add-resources:

-deploy-ant:

-deploy-without-pw:
     [echo] Deploying dist/EJBModule1.jar
      [get] Getting: http://localhost:4848/__asadmin/deploy?path=/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/EJBModule1/dist/EJBModule1.jar&force=true&name=EJBModule1
      [get] To: /tmp/gfv31064357726
   [delete] Deleting: /tmp/gfv31064357726

-deploy-with-pw:

-run-deploy-am:

-post-nbmodule-run-deploy:

post-run-deploy:

-do-update-breakpoints:

run-deploy:

run:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/EJBModule1$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/EJBModule1$ asadmin list-applications
EJBModule1  <ejb>  
Command list-applications executed successfully.
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/EJBModule1$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/EJBModule1$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/EJBModule1$
```

glassfish log:

```
[2017-11-06T16:40:44.695-0800] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=43 _ThreadName=admin-listener(2)] [timeMillis: 1510015244695] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2017-11-06T16:40:44.699-0800] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=43 _ThreadName=admin-listener(2)] [timeMillis: 1510015244699] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2017-11-06T16:40:44.746-0800] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-EJB-00054] [javax.enterprise.ejb.container] [tid: _ThreadID=43 _ThreadName=admin-listener(2)] [timeMillis: 1510015244746] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Portable JNDI names for EJB FooBean: [java:global/EJBModule1/FooBean!net.bounceme.dur.ejb.NewSessionBeanRemote, java:global/EJBModule1/FooBean]]]

[2017-11-06T16:40:44.746-0800] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-EJB-00055] [javax.enterprise.ejb.container] [tid: _ThreadID=43 _ThreadName=admin-listener(2)] [timeMillis: 1510015244746] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Glassfish-specific (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB FooBean: [ejb/FooBean, ejb/FooBean#net.bounceme.dur.ejb.NewSessionBeanRemote]]]

[2017-11-06T16:40:44.797-0800] [glassfish 4.1] [WARN] [] [org.jboss.weld.Event] [tid: _ThreadID=43 _ThreadName=admin-listener(2)] [timeMillis: 1510015244797] [levelValue: 900] [[
  WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.]]

[2017-11-06T16:40:44.800-0800] [glassfish 4.1] [WARN] [] [org.jboss.weld.Event] [tid: _ThreadID=43 _ThreadName=admin-listener(2)] [timeMillis: 1510015244800] [levelValue: 900] [[
  WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.]]

[2017-11-06T16:40:44.803-0800] [glassfish 4.1] [WARN] [] [org.jboss.weld.Event] [tid: _ThreadID=43 _ThreadName=admin-listener(2)] [timeMillis: 1510015244803] [levelValue: 900] [[
  WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.]]

[2017-11-06T16:40:45.010-0800] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=43 _ThreadName=admin-listener(2)] [timeMillis: 1510015245010] [levelValue: 800] [[
  EJBModule1 was successfully deployed in 321 milliseconds.]]

^C
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ tail -f GlassFish_Server/glassfish/domains/dur/logs/server.log
```

Is that not how to lookup the `EJB`?  Client code:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.ejb.client;

import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.Name;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class App {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName());

    public void run() throws NamingException {
        log.fine("looking up jndi");
        Context context = null;
        context = new InitialContext();
        context.lookup("java:global/EJBModule1/FooBean");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new App().run();
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your code is ok, but you need bean interfaces and parameters and returned objects in client classpath too.

Modify this line:

```
context.lookup("java:global/EJBModule1/FooBean");
```

To:

```
NewSessionBeanRemote bean = (NewSessionBeanRemote) context.lookup("java:global/EJBModule1/FooBean");
```

And resolve classpath problems. It will work.